# Snakemake rule to merge files into one

Tags: snakemake

I am working with a large ensemble of climate model outputs with snakemake. Lets say I have the following set of files:

```
tas_AFR-44_NOAA-GFDL-GFDL-ESM2M_rcp45_r1i1p1_SMHI-RCA4_v1_mon_200601-201012.nc
tas_AFR-44_NOAA-GFDL-GFDL-ESM2M_rcp45_r1i1p1_SMHI-RCA4_v1_mon_201101-202012.nc
tas_AFR-44_NOAA-GFDL-GFDL-ESM2M_rcp45_r1i1p1_SMHI-RCA4_v1_mon_202101-203012.nc
tas_AFR-44_NOAA-GFDL-GFDL-ESM2M_rcp45_r1i1p1_SMHI-RCA4_v1_mon_203101-204012.nc

tas_AFR-44_NOAA-GFDL-GFDL-ESM2M_rcp85_r1i1p1_SMHI-RCA4_v1_mon_200601-201012.nc
tas_AFR-44_NOAA-GFDL-GFDL-ESM2M_rcp85_r1i1p1_SMHI-RCA4_v1_mon_201101-202012.nc
tas_AFR-44_NOAA-GFDL-GFDL-ESM2M_rcp85_r1i1p1_SMHI-RCA4_v1_mon_202101-203012.nc
tas_AFR-44_NOAA-GFDL-GFDL-ESM2M_rcp85_r1i1p1_SMHI-RCA4_v1_mon_203101-204012.nc
```

Note that the file names are largely the same, apart from the emissions scenario code in the middle (`rcp45` or `rcp85`).  I would like to merge these all together into two files, one per emissions scearnio, with the timestamps removed. The output filenames would be

```
tas_AFR-44_NOAA-GFDL-GFDL-ESM2M_rcp45_r1i1p1_SMHI-RCA4_v1_mon.nc
tas_AFR-44_NOAA-GFDL-GFDL-ESM2M_rcp85_r1i1p1_SMHI-RCA4_v1_mon.nc
```

This snakemake workflow needs to be driven by the files available on disk - it is impossible to work backwards from the endpoint. I am using `glob_wildcards` to help me along the way and this is what I have so far:

```
rule all_outputs:
    input:
       "tas_AFR-44_NOAA-GFDL-GFDL-ESM2M_rcp45_r1i1p1_SMHI-RCA4_v1_mon.nc",
        "tas_AFR-44_NOAA-GFDL-GFDL-ESM2M_rcp85_r1i1p1_SMHI-RCA4_v1_mon.nc"
                
rule single_output:
    output:
        "{prefix}_evaluation_{suffix}.nc"
    input:
        glob_wildcards("{prefix}_evaluation_{suffix}_{date}.nc")
    run:
        #Do some magic to merge them (not relevant here)
        print(output)  #As a test to see what's going on
```

This doesn't seem to be connecting up correctly however - here's what I get when I run the workflow:

```
Building DAG of jobs...
MissingInputException in rule all_outputs in file /dmidata/projects/klimaatlas/KAPy/Snakefile, line 154:
Missing input files for rule all_outputs:
    affected files:
        tas_AFR-44_NOAA-GFDL-GFDL-ESM2M_rcp85_r1i1p1_SMHI-RCA4_v1_mon.nc
        tas_AFR-44_NOAA-GFDL-GFDL-ESM2M_rcp45_r1i1p1_SMHI-RCA4_v1_mon.nc
```

How can I create such a rule that is driven by what's on disk, rather than what I wish to have instead?

Comment: The two files you list as input in your version of `rule all` aren't connected to the output of any rule you share here. That makes it hard to tell how they aren't connecting up. Or at least from what you shared here I'm not seeing it. And if this is the actual situation then that is the answer. Something has to have those two files listed as output. "How can I create such a rule that is driven by what's on disk, rather than what I wish to have instead?" Usually the answer to that sort of question is the use of a checkpoint, see for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71094166/8508004).

Comment: However, I am not really seeing that necessary here because as written you know the input and endpoint? Maybe that is not the case? And as your describe it they do connect in a way that you can indicate if you make use of Snakemake's input functions. But maybe I'm missing something since your provided code isn't a minimal working example in any way and seems a tiny snippet?

Answer (score 1):

Without more detail, this is more or less what I would do:

```
import glob

emicode = ['rcp45', 'rcp85']

wildcard_constraints:
    emicode = '|'.join([re.escape(x) for x in emicode]),

rule all:
    input:
        expand('someprefix_{emicode}_somesuffix.nc', emicode=emicode),

rule merge:
    input:
        nc=lambda wc: sorted(glob.glob(f'*_{wc.emicode}_*.nc')),
    output:
        nc='someprefix_{emicode}_somesuffix.nc',
    shell:
        r"""
        cat {input.nc} > {output.nc}
        """
```

Here I have hard-coded the `emicode` list. In reality, you may want to glob the files on the disk and use python code to extract the emission codes from their names to create the `emicode` list. I would say that is a different question that has more to do with python and your specific scenario than with snakemake.

The `wildcard_constraints` section may not be needed, but I prefer to add it to effectively turn off the regex matching of wildcards and match exactly the given codes.

I don't have much sympathy for the `glob_wildcards` function since it does too much stuff under the hood, but it's probably just me...